# Auto input focused element jQuery ui (autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I use jQuery UI to give autocomplete suggestions based on a SQL database. This works perfectly, however I would like (just like google) to automatically fill the input with the currently selected/focused (li) element.

```
input name="movie" type="text" id="titles" class="input-field-primary" placeholder="Test"  method="GET" autofocus>

    $(function() {
        $( '#titles' ).autocomplete({
            source: 'includes/search.php',
            minLength: 3,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $('.ui-autocomplete').off('menufocus hover mouseover mouseenter');
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    $(".ui-autocomplete").css('display', 'none');
    });
            }


        });
    })
```

Comment: have you seen the `select` method which autocomplete has? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: I tried the following: select: function(event,ui) {
     alert("selected");
    },
However, this only alerts me after I click  enter or really select an item. While I want to do something when one of the suggestions is focused by the user.

Comment: remove the `open` method and add `focus` event. It will work. I have created a sample for you https://jsfiddle.net/8egw1m8w/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great!

Comment: Cool. I have provided the working example below as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `focus` event on `autocomplete`.

I have mocked the `source` below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#titles').autocomplete({
    source: ['aaaa', 'bbbb'], // replace this with your AJAX call
    minLength: 3,

    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#titles").val(ui.value)
    },

    focus: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui)
      $("#titles").val(ui.value)
    }


  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input name="movie" type="text" id="titles" class="input-field-primary" placeholder="Test" method="GET" autofocus>
```

Comment: The only problem I have now is that the open part in the original function is needed for the autosuggest to work properly on iOS devices. If this is not in there, then you have to click twice on a suggestion for it to appear in the input field. However, it seems as of simply adding the open part makes the select and focus not working again. Any ideas?